# How to check if a cell of a Dataframe exists as a key in a dict, and if it does, check if another cell in same row exists in a list in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe like this

```
   colA   colB   colC    colD
   1      1a     Yes     Yes
   1      1b     Yes     Yes
   2      2a     Yes     Yes
   2      2b     Yes     Yes
   2      2c     Yes     Yes
   3      3a     Yes     Yes
   4      4a     Yes     Yes
```

Say I have a dictionary like this

```
filterDict = {
   "1" : ["1a","1b"]
   "2" : ["2a","2b"]
}
```

I want it so that if in colA a value exists as a key, check if colB in that same row exists in the value list of the dict for that key so that the resulting dataframe would look like this

```
   colA   colB   colC    colD
   1      1a     No      No
   1      1b     No      No
   2      2a     No      No
   2      2b     No      No
   2      2c     Yes     Yes
   3      3a     Yes     Yes
   4      4a     Yes     Yes
```

I am relatively new to pandas and am unsure how to do this.
What I previously had was something hardcoded like this

```
mask = ((df["colA"] == "1") & (df["colB"].isin(["1a","1b"])) |
       ((df["colB"] == "2") & (df["colB"].isin(["2a","2b"]))

df.loc[mask,["colC","colD"]] = ["No","No"]
```

But I would like this to be dynamic so that it could be put in the dict format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the `fitersDict` into list of tuples then create a multindex from it, the use `Multindex.isin` to test from the occurrence of multiindex in the columns `colA`, `colB` of given dataframe

```
i1 = df.set_index(['colA', 'colB']).index
i2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((a, b) for a, l in filterDict.items() for b in l)

mask = ~i1.isin(i2)
df['colC'], df['colD'] = mask, mask
```

---

```
  colA colB   colC   colD
0    1   1a  False  False
1    1   1b  False  False
2    2   2a  False  False
3    2   2b  False  False
4    2   2c   True   True
5    3   3a   True   True
6    4   4a   True   True
```

Comment: Thank I think this is the closest to what I want without using row iteration or df.apply

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if str(row['colA']) in filterDict:
        if row['colB'] in filterDict[str(row['colA'])]:
            df.loc[index, 'colC'] = 'No'
            df.loc[index, 'colD'] = 'No'
            continue

    df.loc[index, 'colC'] = 'Yes'
    df.loc[index, 'colD'] = 'Yes'
```

Based on your expected output, I've assumed `'No'` if a match is found, otherwise `'Yes'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative:

```
df[['colC', 'colD']] = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df[['colA', 'colB']].apply(
    lambda _: (
        'NO' if str(_[0]) in filterDict else 'YES',
        'NO' if _[1] in filterDict.get(str(_[0]), []) else 'YES'
    ), axis=1
).values)).T
```

Or in the case where ColB must equal ColC you can simply try this:

```
df['colC'] = df[['colA', 'colB']].apply(

    lambda _: 'NO' if str(_[0]) in filterDict and _[1] in filterDict.get(str(_[0]), []) else 'YES',
    axis=1
)
df['colD'] = df['colC'].copy()
```